# Priority queue doesnt work as it must if I remove a line of code

Tags: python, data-structures, priority-queue

I have come up with this code to implement a priority queue however I dont understand why it works. I just got lucky I guess. I had this gut feeling I had to put there. Anyway I  put a comment below the line highlighting the code I dont understand.

```py
class queueNode:
    def __init__(self,val,nextNode,prior):
        self.val = val
        self.nextNode = nextNode
        self.prior = prior

class priorityQueue:
    def __init__(self,baseNode):
        self.baseNode = baseNode

    def addNode(self,insertedNode):
        current = self.baseNode

#             vvvvvvvvvvvv
        while current.next and current.prior > insertedNode.prior:
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^

            current = current.nextNode
        target = current.nextNode
        current.nextNode = insertedNode
        insertedNode.nextNode = target

    def deleteNode():
        current = self.baseNode
        target = current.nextNode
        self.baseNode = target
        del current

    def print(self):
        current = self.baseNode
        while current:
            print("Value:",current.val+" ")
            print("Priority:\n",current.prior)
            current = current.nextNode

q1 = queueNode("A",None,1)
myQueue = priorityQueue(q1)
q2 = queueNode("B",None,1)
q3 = queueNode("C",None,0)
q4 = queueNode("D",None,0)
q5 = queueNode("E",None,1)

myQueue.addNode(q2)
myQueue.addNode(q3)
myQueue.addNode(q4)
myQueue.addNode(q5)

myQueue.print()
```

When I remove the highlighted code it shows me an error that NoneType doesnt contain an argument named prior, I guess I am running into some NoneType Exception but the code is very complicated and cannot understand why?

Comment: Because without that code, you can keep looping until `current` becomes None.  You must stop before you reach the end, so `current` is a valid node.  That's what you're doing.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks a lot I understand it now.I just saw one implementation of the linked list and that line of code has to be there for the reasons you pointed out.

Comment: In the future, use some other way to highlight the code in question. Surrounding it with two asterisks doesn't make it stand out in a quick scan. I'd suggest putting a comment right before the line in question so that it really stands out.

Comment: Is your requirement to implement a priority queue from scratch, or are you just unaware of the [use of the heapq module to implement one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes)?

Comment: Implementation from scratch